# Possible Memory Leak in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, memory, nsstring, memory-leaks, retain

Just starting out with Objective-C after spending years in Python.. still trying to wrap my head around some concepts.. I can't seem to figure this out but every time I either increment up or deduct from `myCount` it retains the older variable in memory. I am using ARC so shouldn't it autorelease? I have a feeling it has to do with `self.varOfMyCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myCount];`

Header:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet NSMenu *statusMenu;
    NSStatusItem *statusItem;
}
- (IBAction)itemOne:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)itemTwo:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)itemThree:(id)sender;



@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *varOfMyCount;

@end

int myCount = 0;
```

Implementation:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength ];
    [statusItem setMenu:statusMenu];
    [statusItem setTitle:@"Status"];
    [statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
}

- (IBAction)itemOne:(id)sender {
    myCount++;
    self.varOfMyCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myCount];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.varOfMyCount);
    [statusItem setTitle:self.varOfMyCount];
}

- (IBAction)itemTwo:(id)sender {
    myCount = myCount-1;
    self.varOfMyCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myCount];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.varOfMyCount);
    [statusItem setTitle:self.varOfMyCount];

}

- (IBAction)itemThree:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Quit.");
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] terminate:nil];
}
@end
```

Comment: How did you determine that these instances were not being released?

Comment: In Activity Monitor, as I incremented up it was eating more memory.

Comment: Did you use Instruments to view the exact allocations (and any leaks)?

Comment: I just did but I'm not sure what I'm looking for: http://i.imgur.com/BmnfXQA.png

Comment: That doesn't look to be progressively growing. Does the app crash? If you run it for a few minutes does the live byte count grow? If you take a heap shot between each button press what does it show?

Comment: I ran it again with a slight pause before I started incrementing: http://i.imgur.com/LhXUfzu.png I've noticed that if I remove any instance of `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myCount];` it doesn't eat memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your images, it doesn't really look like there is a problem. In order for your app to run it does need to use memory. Depending on what you do it will use different amounts.

Using `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myCount];` requires more than you might think because you are asking the system to parse your format string and inject parameters into it. Parsing and scanning a string isn't a trivial operation.

In a number of cases when memory is allocated for a task it isn't released. This is usually the case when it's expensive to create (like the scanning structure, or parts of it) or is likely to be used repeatedly.

You should be worried if the memory grows bigger each time you do the same activity and return to your 'transient' state. Consider running multiple iterations of your button push and, between each push, take a heap shot. If each heap shot (apart from the first and last) are empty (or very close to it) then everything's good. If not, it will show exactly what isn't being released.

Comment: Ah! So I see.. so am I looking at this correctly that the large chunk of memory used was in relation to loading up a font. http://imgur.com/a/hQIum More specifically because it's the first time it increments and changes the status bar label?

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for your assistance. I feel I need to get more in depth with Instruments. Do you have any recommendations for someone coming from Python moving to Objc? I'm trying to find a good start for threading. Here's an example of what I'm able to do in Python but want to carry over to Objc in methods: https://gist.github.com/granda/6335158

Comment: High level API is operation queues https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html low level is GCD https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html